# Software to view all HTTP connections made by your computer?

Tags: internet, http, sniffing

I would like to see all HTTP connections (with free and preferably open source software), and their full responses made by my computer. A performance hit doesn't matter, as I will use this only in short bursts.

The reason I'm asking is because I want to see if I could get Hulu to work for me in Canada by using my web server as a proxy that intercepts checks for my location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a great Windows utility for tracking and observing HTTP traffic. Though I don't think you'll be able to get around Hulu by altering your responses. (I think they do a location IP check)

Comment: I found that Hulu accesses releasegeo.hulu.com/geoCheck with Fiddler, thanks for the recommendation! Now I just have to find out what response Hulu sends to those from the USA...

Comment: If you are using Firefox, Firebug does a good job analyzing network traffic as well.

Answer (score 2):

wireshark is a packet sniffer, you can use to do that, but you'll have to sort out http and https from everything else, DNS, and such

Comment: Wireshark not only monitor http or https (OSI layer level 7) but also TCP and IP (OSI layer level 2 and 3)..it's great utillity

Answer (score 0):

If you have a webserver with a US ip than you can tunnel your connection to it via ssh and watch hulu on your pc

Answer (score 0):

hulu.com will see the proxy's IP address. So you really don't need to bother monkeying with geoCheck, just use a proxy in the USA.
See this article [How to bypass the Hulu.com location check using a socks5 proxy](http://huluexposed.wordpress.com/2008/03/17/how-to-bypass-the-hulucom-location-check-using-a-socks5-proxy-2/) for details.